# Login With Reactjs not working as they say Dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement a login in my reactjs application. I am quite new to react as well.

My Application contains several components such as about, navigation , login, signup, post, notification etc.

Here, There are components such as about, signup that a user can access without login but there are others such as notifications, posting that you can only access after login.

I am currently working on the login to the application. I have created a Login Component and in the login component, I have the function

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const credential = this.state.user;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if( credential.username && credential.password){
      dispatch(userActions.login(credential.username, credential.password));
      //this.loginUser(credential);
    }
}
```

I have imported import { userActions } from '../_actions'; to the login component.

In the UserActions, I have defined the login function as follows:

But when I submit the form, I get the error, TypeError: dispatch is not a function.

```
function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    };

    return fetch(URL_LOGIN, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        });
}
```

Any help on this error will be greatly appreciated. 
Also, I will be grateful if someone can give me a very simple guide that can help me with this login process on my application. 
Note: I didn't start the application with redux and I just installed into my application, and I try to follow the tutorials here
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example
though I am facing lots of difficulties with it.
Also, My API is in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the access to dispatch method which is available with the store through
react-redux connect and Provider. you need to send your actions bound with dispatch. you can do this using two methods. The first method is simple but gets redundant when using multiple actions. The second one is what you use normally in react-redux applications

Method 1:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    yourValues: 1,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    login: (...rest) => {
      dispatch(login(...rest))
    },
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Method 2:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux"
import * as LoginActions from "/your-login-path"
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    yourValues: 1,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    ...LoginActions,
  })
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourComponent)
```

Once you are done with this implementation, you will be able to access
login method in props. Now you can call login directly like this

```
const { login } = this.props
login(yourarguments)
```

Please read more about these on the redux website.

Comment: So where do I write the above functions ?? in the store ??

Comment: Generally, its written in Containers or the dumcomponents. For now, you can try writing in the same file where your component is defined. ANd change the export as mentioned in the answer